# PHP Result on ftp_up success

Tags: php, foreach, ftp, response, put

Sry for asking so much [ 3rd in 2 days ]
this time I want to make it so when ftp_put uploads a file it wont show the result each time it uploads , like "Success Success" but I want it to say only when it finishes to upload all the files.
My current code:

```
 foreach (glob("black/*") as $filename)
 if(ftp_put($conn, $ftpFolder . basename($filename) , $filename, FTP_BINARY)) {
 echo "sall goodman"; }
 else { echo "not goot bruh"; }
}
```

[ dont look at the answers right now, its just for duh lulz and testing ]

Thanks in advance guys, You are really helping me out :)

Comment: take out the echos from the for loop and put like `echo "done"` outside the for loop?

Comment: But what if it fails? Could you detail a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just comment the statement , **`echo "sall goodman"`** and you are good to go such that you won't get the repeated success message.
I have extended your example a bit, If all files are uploaded successfully you get the message **`All files have been successfully uploaded`** , else say if some 2 files failed on upload then you will get **`2 file(s) have been failed during upload`**.

```
$totFiles = 0;
$successUploadFiles=0;
foreach (glob("black/*") as $filename)
 if(ftp_put($conn, $ftpFolder . basename($filename) , $filename, FTP_BINARY)) {
 //echo "sall goodman";
 $successUploadFiles++;
 }
 else { echo "not goot bruh"; }
$totFiles++;
}

if($totFiles == $successUploadFiles)
{
echo "All files have been successfully uploaded";
}
else
{
echo $totFiles-$successUploadFiles." file(s) have been failed during upload";
}
```